# Form Validation doesn't stop submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">1</span> Your Information</legend>
      <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
      <input type="email" name="field2" id="contact"placeholder="Contact Information (Email, Phone Number, etc.) *">
      <input type="location" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, Hodge Hall, exact address, etc.)*">
      <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important"></textarea>
      <label for="job">Urgency:</label>
      <select id="job" name="field5">
        <optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
          <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
          <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
          <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">2</span>Task that needs completion</legend>
      <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Let Us Know How We Can Help!*"></input>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="push();validateForm();"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm using simple JS validation function which gets called "onClick" my submit button. My error messages get displayed correctly if someone submits an empty form, however, once you press "OK" on that alert, the form still gets submitted. I have a similar validation system on a different form and it runs smoothly.... Any modifications to my code, even if it doesn't solve the overall problem, would be appreciated.

```js
  function validateForm() {
      var errormessage = "";
      if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
          errormessage += "Please enter your name. \n";
          document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      if (document.getElementById('contact').value == "") {
          errormessage += "Please enter your contact. \n";
          document.getElementById('contact').style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      if (document.getElementById('location').value == "") {
          errormessage += "Tell us where to come! \n";
          document.getElementById('location').style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      if (document.getElementById('task').value == "") {
          errormessage += "Tell us how we can help! \n";
          document.getElementById('task').style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      if (errormessage != "") {
          alert(errormessage);
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  };
```

Comment: Also add `HTML`.. How `validateForm` is invoked ?

Comment: Following up on Rayon's request, can you please show how the validateForm function is being used?

Comment: I just added the HTML, thanks  @Rayon

Comment: `onClick="push();return validateForm();"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent the form submission, the event must be stopped. The click handler setup will bubble to submission because it does not provide a way to stop the event.

An easy way is returning false, as you have attempted in the shown function. However, that return value is not being used. Note that your inline event handler looks like this

```
onClick="push();validateForm();"
```

As the value from validateForm is never used, the event handler continues on after the call to validation. The fix is to use the return value

```
onClick="push();return validateForm();"
```

Which will now properly stop the event if validation fails.